# Program using pointers in C crashes. Unable to find the mistake

Tags: c

I have written a program which accepts the number of students and the number of subjects. I need to accepts the marks in all subjects for each student and print each students total marks.
I have used pointers instead of an array since we do not know the number of students/subjects.
The function causing the problem might be this one:
n=students,m=subjects and sm is a pointer object of a structure which contains pointer 'marks'.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void accept(int,int); //Function Prototype
void calc(int,int);//Function Prototype
void print(int);//Function Prototype
struct student{
    float *marks;
}*sm;
float *total;
int main(){
    int n,m;
    printf("Enter number of students(N) and number of subjects(M) \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    sm=malloc(n);
    sm->marks=malloc(m);
    total=malloc(n);
    accept(n,m);
    calc(n,m);
    print(n);
    return 0;
}
void accept(int n,int m){ //Accepts data
    int i,p;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Enter the marks of student %d in each subject in order and separated by a space/line \n",i+1);
    for(p=0;p<m;p++){
        scanf("%f",(sm+i)->marks+p);
        }
    }
}
void calc(int n,int m){ //Calculates total marks
    int i,p,tot=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(p=0;p<m;p++){
            tot+=*((sm+i)->marks+p);
        }
        *(total+i)=tot;
        tot=0;
    }
}
void print(int n){//Print the total marks of each student
    int i,tot=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Total marks for student %d is:%0.2f \n",i+1,*(total+i));
    }
}
```

The program crashes whenever the number of students>1 . I do not understand why and I have tried many ways to fix it but none have worked so far.
What is my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What is `sm`? What is `(sm+i)->marks`? Are they pointers? Have they been properly initialized?

Comment: `sm=malloc(n);`  N students will require more than N bytes of memory.

Answer (score 2):

In your `main` function you have this line:

```
sm=malloc(n);
```

That allocates `n` ***bytes***. Not `n` structure elements. Therefore you will very likely go far out of bounds of the memory you allocate and have *undefined behavior*.

You need to do

```
sm = malloc(n * sizeof *sm);  // Allocates n structures
```

And then you make it worse by treating `sm` as a pointer to a single structure when it's supposed to be an array.

Comment: "That allocates n bytes. Not n structure elements."  
Ohh! Its my first time using malloc so I got confused a bit. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to malloc memory for EVERY sm->mark.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    sm[i].marks=malloc(m*sizeof(float));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Points:

> You need to assign memory for each student i.e. n students in your
>   case:

```
sm = malloc(n * sizeof (*sm));
```

> Inside structure, you used float* and while using malloc, you are
>   using int i.e. m, which is not a good sign, same thing for total also.
>   Update it in your code.

.